# LinkedIn Api secod time logging Not displaying login Window in iOS

Tags: ios, ios8, linkedin-api, xcode6

I am currently working an new app with XCode 6. In that app, I integrated LinkedIn Api from following link

**https://github.com/jeyben/IOSLinkedInAPI**

I created APP API in developer.linkedin.com, its worked fine (yesterday). Today I opend my app and tried to login using login button clicking, but the loginview is not displaying, I tried somany times and created also new api for that app, but no useful, Could anyone give suggestions to fix this issue.

I checked everything in my side for API Key and Secret Key. Its very strange, yesterday its worked pretty, but today its not showing Login window after clicked the login button from my app. Thanks in advanced

Comment: finally i found solution myself for this, before coming to login class, in my previous class added following code and then my issue solved in linkedin api of my login page, I hope this would helps somebody in future!
    AppDelegate *appDel=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    LoginViewController *loginVC=[[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    appDel.window.rootViewController=loginVC;
    [appDel.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    loginVC=nil;